# How to query UUID stored as BINARY(16) using JPQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, hibernate, uuid

We are using UUID as our primary keys

Annotated as follows

```
@Id
@Column(columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")
protected UUID id;
```

We generate the UUID ourselves and that works fine

However a problem arises when we manually insert for example

```
INSERT PINSUS..job ([id], [version], [date_created], [description], [job_url], [last_updated], [name]) VALUES (CAST('30783030-3030-3030-3030-303030303030' AS VARBINARY(16)), CAST(0 AS Numeric(19, 0)), CAST(N'2018-01-23 12:29:02.653' AS DateTime), N'Job for nomis', N'http://localhost:8086/batch/operations/jobs/nomisLoadJob', CAST(N'2018-01-23 12:29:02.653' AS DateTime), N'nomisLoadJob')
```

Which stores the id as 0x33303738333033302D333033302D3330 according to Microsoft Management Studio

However looking at it using jetbrains datagrip the id shows as 30783030-3030-30

Which since it seems to be partial string of the original UUID we attempted to insert but has been truncated when converting to BINARY 16

How should one insert a UUID manually using SQL for MSSQL Server?

At the moment if we try and use a JPQL query with the original UUID we get back no results.

Comment: Why are you using `binary(16)`? SQL Server has the uniqueidentifier datatype for UUIDs?

Comment: @DaleK That was just to reduce the storage size when testing. The code will be used by SQL Server and Oracle. The default column type for SQL Server is binary(255) using hibernate. We can't tell it to use uniqueidentifier as it does not exist in Oracle.